# change arrayadapter layout resource when button clicked

Tags: android, layout, resources, listadapter

I have a `listview`, it shows up great, however when I click on my "edit" action button, I want the `listview` to use a different layout resource so that buttons show up beside each item in the list.

```
layout before: listitem_routine
layout I want after "edit" action button clicked: listitem_routine_edit
```

heres my code that works:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_routines);

    datasource = new RoutinesDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    List<Routine> values = datasource.getAllRoutines();

    ArrayAdapter<Routine> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Routine>(this,
        R.layout.listitem_routine, R.id.listitem_routine_name, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      ArrayAdapter<Routine> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Routine>) getListAdapter();
      // Handle item selection
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.button_routines_edit:
            // change the list view adapter resource layout to *_edit
            // hide this button and show the "done editing (checkmark)" button
          return true;
      default:
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
  }
```

I know that the case for `R.id.button_routines_edit` works because I made toast when it was clicked. and it was delicious. I since removed that code...

but any ways, how would I go about changing the layout resource when `R.id.button_routines_edit` is clicked? all the code is there, I just don't know how to go about changing the layout resource and then obviously updating the `listview` to display the new row layout...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reload the listview with the new resource after clicking the action button as follows.

```
  @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

  // Handle item selection
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.button_routines_edit:
         ArrayAdapter<Routine> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Routine>(this,
    R.layout.listitem_routine_edit, R.id.listitem_routine_name, values);

setListAdapter(adapter);
      return true;
  default:
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah i figured it out, i also had to re-grab the list values inside this function via `List<Routine> values = datasource.getAllRoutines();`